# Images are removed from the cache even if they should be far within the limit

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app with 8 local images that I'm trying to load when the app starts using `precacheImage` inside `didChangeDependencies()`. And that works fine if I only preload five of the images, but as soon as I try to load all of them, or go to the page where the last three images are, all of them disappears from the cache. No image is larger than 1 MB in size, so there is no way they can be over the limit of 100 MB.

Another thing that I find strange is that `ImageCache().currentSize` returns 0 even after caching the images, so maybe I have understood all of this wrong?

I haven't found a lot of information about this either, apart form SO threads and GitHub issues that didn't really help in my case.